# How applications look like the same in all iphone and ipad models

Tags: css, cross-browser, resolution, mobile-website

I am creating a mobile version of my website and I wonder every iphone and ipad models have different resolutions but applications or websites look like the same..

For example, my header bar looks like the same in ipad and ipad mini or all iphones.

```
div#header-iphone
{
width:320px;
height:45px;
}

div#header-ipad
{
width:1024px;
height:45px;
}
```

iPad2's display resolution is 1024×768 and iPad 3rd has 2,048 × 1,536 resolution but my header bar (1024px width) looks like the same in both models..

I am a little confused about this, can you explain how this happens or suggest a source explains this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good css framework available named as twitter bootstrap. This framework consists lot of responsive designs, which works in different screens having different resolutions like desktop, laptop, ipad, iphone, ipod etc. You can go through there website, download the css files they have used and explore inside that. How they are doing it. Hope it helps.